# Getting permissions on Android version 7

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-4.4-kitkat, android-7.0-nougat

I am developing a small application for sending SMS for Android. When you install an .apk **Android 4.4** asks for `permission` to send `SMS` messages from the device. But **Android 7** does not ask any permissions at all. However, you need to turn on SMS send permission manually in settings to make application work properly.

Is there any way to show permissions during install process on all Android systems?

Comment: For android 7 you need to get permission from the user during runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it/41957460#41957460 Give permission run time using above link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android 6.0 (API level 23) you have to request the permissions at runtime. Most application do that when the user is starting the app for the first time.

To check if you have the permission already, use

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
```

to check if you can read SMS.
Return will be `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` if the app has the permission already, else it will return `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`.

To request permission, use

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

where `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS` is an app defined int constant.

[The corresponding documentation will give more detail about this.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Please note: You need to define the corresponding `<uses-permission>` elements in your Manifest and then request the permission at runtime.

To work around this problem, simply drop the targeted SDK version below 23.